# Wrong answer in online judge

Tags: c++

Codeforces problem 131A-http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/131/A
I am using Dev C++ 5.5.2 on Windows 7(I have entered language as Visual Studio 2010 C++).Although,I am getting the correct output on running my solution on computer,I am getting wrong answer in test case 3 on Codeforces.

Judge's log:

est: #3, time: 0 ms., memory: 0 KB, exit code: 0, checker exit code: 1, verdict: WRONG_ANSWER
Input
cAPSlOCK
Output
Capslock
Answer
cAPSlOCK
Checker Log
wrong answer 1st words differ - expected: 'cAPSlOCK', found: 'Capslock'

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
char a[101];
int i,b;
int main()
{
    cin>>a;
    b=a[0];if(b>90)
    {
        b=b-32;
        a[0]=b;
    }
    for(i=1;a[i]!=NULL;i++)
    {
        b=a[i];
        if(b<97)
        {
            b=b+32;
            a[i]=b;
        }
    }
    cout<<a;
}
```

What should I change in my solution for it to work correctly in online judge too?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What kind of code is this?  What are `90` and `97`?  And `32`?

Comment: If the word is not all caps (except for the first character), the word should not change.  This is clearly not the case here.  So you are not getting the correct output on your computer.

Comment: @PlasmaHH-Sorry for being vague.What is wrong in my solution that I am getting wrong answer for test case 'cAPSLOCK'?

Comment: @IamintheEmpireBusiness: the input is cAPSlOCK, not cAPSLOCK.

Comment: You are lowercasing a[i] regardless... i.e. you go into the for loop and "lower case" all the "upper case" "letters" (well chars <97), perhaps you need  an "if" somewhere

Comment: @JamesKanze-Lowercase a-z have ASCII codes 97-133 and uppercase A-Z have ASCII codes 65-90.Difference between ASCII codes for uppercase and lowercase of an alphabet is 32.

Comment: @doctorlove-I have an if condition in the for loop.If any alphabet from 2nd alphabet of the word in uppercase,it is lowered.

Comment: @IamintheEmpireBusiness And?  What machine today uses ASCII?  And why would you want to obfuscate by using manifest constants.  And of course, the fact that `b > 90` doesn't mean that `b` is upper case, even in ASCII.  ('{' is 123, for example.)

Comment: @JamesKanze-I am relatively new to programming.I will only learn with time.In the problem,the input string will have only lowercase and uppercase alphabets.Hence,it is safe to assume 'b>90' will be lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you should use the standard functions `isupper`,
etc. (in `<ctype.h>`—just remember that you must convert
any `char` to `unsigned char` before using them).  In
particular, your code seems to assume that 1) the encoding is
ASCII (although no modern machine uses ASCII), and 2) that the
word only contains alphabetic characters.  (You also fail to
check if the input succeeded.)

Second, the specified condition involves the entire string, not
just the first character.  Just testing the first character
cannot possibly suffice; you must check every character in the
string.  (The actual specification of the problem is not too
clear; what does "all letters except the first" mean if there is
only a single letter?)

Third, you loop on the tranformation regardless of the results
of your `if`.  Which is certainly wrong.

Fourth, you don't swap case; you only mangle values less than
97.

There are two separate problems here.  The first is to determine
whether the caps lock key has been set.  The simplest way is
something like:

```
if ( std::find_if( word.begin() + 1,
                   word.end(),
                   []( unsigned char ch ) { return !isupper( ch ); } )
        == word.end() )
```

(This is a simplification, since it returns true for all one
character strings.  But this is one possible interpretation of
the specifications, although I don't think a very intuitive
one.)

If you don't want to use functions like `std::find_if`, you
should factor this out into a separate function:

```
bool
capsLockSet( std::string const& word )
{
    auto current = word.begin() + 1;
    while ( current != word.end()
            && isupper( static_cast<unsigned char>( *current ) ) ) {
        ++ current;
    }
    return current == word.end();
}
```

Similarly, you can use `std::transform` for the transformation
(only done if the above returns true), or factor the loop out
into a separate function; in both cases, the first character
will require special handling, because if it is lower case, you
have to convert it to upper.  (*IF* you have a precondition that
the only characters you will see are ASCII letters, then you can
toggle between upper and lower by `ch ^= 0x20`.  I'd recommend
against it, since it is so dependent on the encoding, *and* the
fact that there are only letters present, and no other
characters.)

Comment: Over here,high school CS curriculum is too outdated.We are made to use Turbo C++.Hence,many of my approaches may seem outdated.Sorry about that.

Comment: @IamintheEmpireBusiness That probably means that you cannot use `find_if` and `string`, but `<ctype.h>` goes back to the earliest days of C, and is surely present in Turbo C++.  (And there's really no point in learning C++ with an implementation which doesn't support `std::string`.  You're wasting your time.)

Answer (score 1):

About the question "What should I change in my solution for it to work correctly in online judge too?"

The problem states: only change the word if it is all caps apart from the first character.
The error report states: cAPSlOCK should return cAPSlOCK, not Capslock.
So at least there should be a check in your program to output the input if it should not be changed.

About the program: you can use helper functions from [cctype](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/): `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()` and `tolower()` so it's easier for you and us to understand what is going on.

Comment: I was not familiar with these functions.Thanks.